# Input text fields, doesn't animate (material Design)

Tags: html, css, material-design

I have a setup of MDC, but my text field doesn't animate.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sNVe.jpg
This link shows the state it's supposed to be at, and the state my field is at.

The first image is from my site, where you can see the label isn't animating to the top line, as the bottom image is, when entering active state. The bottom image is directly from the Google Material Design demo page.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>

<div class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined">
  <input type="text" id="tf-outlined" class="mdc-text-field__input">
  <label for="tf-outlined" class="mdc-floating-label">Your Name</label>
  <div class="mdc-notched-outline">
    <svg>
                                  <path class="mdc-notched-outline__path"/>
                                </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="mdc-notched-outline__idle"></div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I say thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you look in your brower console if you see any js error ?

Comment: There is, it gives the following. Even though styles are loaded perfectly. 
https://imgur.com/a/L2cO3tl

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem before, you just need to add the following line in your Javascript file:

```
mdc.textField.MDCTextField.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field'));
```

This Javascript code relate the CSS animation label effect with your div .mdc-text-field, and this in the order that you have:

```
<div class="mdc-text-field">
  <input type="text" id="my-text-field" class="mdc-text-field__input">
  <label class="mdc-floating-label" for="my-text-field">Label</label>
  <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
</div>
```

That is why you can't see the correctly label animation in your component. I think the MDC Documentation is good, but poorly specific.

If the problems continue, tell me and I will check your question as soon as possible, greetings!

Edit: I forgot to say; to get all text fields in your website, you have to use:

```
const edtTexts = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-text-field'), function(el) {
  return new mdc.textField.MDCTextField(el);
});
```

So you get an array with each div with **class="mdc-text-field"**. With **document.querySelector** you get the first found object.

Answer (score 1):

use below code snippet. also use `mdc.autoInit();`

```js
mdc.autoInit();
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
          
          
<body>   
     
     <div class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined  mdc-text-field--with-trailing-icon" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextField">
      <i class="material-icons mdc-text-field__icon">delete</i>
      <input type="text" id="my-input" class="mdc-text-field__input">
      <label for="my-input" class="mdc-floating-label">Standard</label>
      <div class="mdc-notched-outline">
        <svg>
          <path class="mdc-notched-outline__path"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="mdc-notched-outline__idle"></div>
    </div>


   <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
           
</body>
```

Comment: How do i use mdc.autoInit();

Comment: no need extra setting or code put it anywhere in JS code or after DOM loaded. also important to add `data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextField" ` check my code. i also added `Material Icons` css library for icon.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

1. You get rid of the `<label></label>`.
2. You add a `placeholder="Your Name"` attribute to your `<input>` tag
3. You hide the placeholder on focus with css

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="tf-outlined" class="mdc-text-field__input" placeholder="Your Name">
```

CSS:

```
.mdc-text-field__input:focus::placeholder {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

**SNIPPET:**

```css
.mdc-text-field__input:focus::placeholder {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>

<div class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined">
  <input type="text" id="tf-outlined" class="mdc-text-field__input" placeholder="Your Name">
  <div class="mdc-notched-outline">
    <svg>
                                  <path class="mdc-notched-outline__path"/>
                                </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="mdc-notched-outline__idle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me.

```
import {MDCTextField} from '@material/textfield';

const mdcTexts = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-text-field'), function(el) {
    return new MDCTextField(el);
});
```